# Woocommerce Select Orders which match multiple meta values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently working on a plugin which was built for a bakery to email reports about orders. They have since opened another store and now the reports need to be split into separate emails depending on store location.

I have the following sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT o.order_item_id, o.order_item_name, o.order_id, po.post_date AS order_date_placed
        FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items AS o
        LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oi ON o.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id
        LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS po ON po.ID = o.order_id
        WHERE oi.meta_key='Collection Date'
        AND oi.meta_value IN ('16/01/2016','17/01/2016','18/01/2016','19/01/2016','20/01/2016','21/01/2016')
        ORDER BY po.post_date ASC, o.order_item_id ASC";
```

This query returns all orders which are to be collected within a specific date range.

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[593]
      public 'order_item_id' => string '19582' (length=5)
      public 'order_item_name' => string '10 Chocolate Cupcakes' (length=21)
      public 'order_id' => string '15234' (length=5)
      public 'order_date_placed' => string '2016-01-14 08:51:31' (length=19)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[592]
      public 'order_item_id' => string '19600' (length=5)
      public 'order_item_name' => string '10 Chocolate Cupcakes' (length=21)
      public 'order_id' => string '15248' (length=5)
      public 'order_date_placed' => string '2016-01-14 15:43:08' (length=19)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[591]
      public 'order_item_id' => string '19603' (length=5)
      public 'order_item_name' => string '10 Chocolate Cupcakes' (length=21)
      public 'order_id' => string '15250' (length=5)
      public 'order_date_placed' => string '2016-01-14 15:45:25' (length=19)
```

I now want to pass an additional criteria that will also limit the return data to a specific store location.

I have tried adding the following to the query but this returns null.

```
WHERE oi.meta_key = 'Pickup Location' 
AND oi.meta_value LIKE '%Address 1%'
```

Only records which are true for both criteria must return.

I do battle to understand why the meta table in wordpress/woocommerce are set up the way they are with so many redundant/duplicate entries.

I'm not sure whether the developer should have used a raw SQL query or whether there is a better solution for this problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this query

```
SELECT o.order_item_id, 
       o.order_item_name, 
       o.order_id, 
       po.post_date AS order_date_placed 
FROM   wp_woocommerce_order_items AS o 
       LEFT JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS oi 
              ON ( o.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id 
                 AND oi.meta_key = 'Collection Date' 
                       AND oi.meta_value IN ( '16/01/2016', '17/01/2016','18/01/2016',
                                              '19/01/2016','20/01/2016', '21/01/2016' ) ) 
                  OR ( oi.meta_key = 'Pickup Location' 
                       AND oi.meta_value LIKE '%Address 1%' ) 
       LEFT JOIN wp_posts AS po 
              ON po.id = o.order_id 
ORDER  BY po.post_date ASC, 
          o.order_item_id ASC
```

And move the filter to `ON` conditions since those belongs to right table